# Automation: Push data from local CSVs to Kusto db tables

Tags: csv, automation, etl, azure-data-explorer, kql

I have different data downloaded from a web page and saved as .csv files on my local directory. I would like to push that data to the tables that I've created on Kusto Explorer and ideally I want this process to be scheduled to take place everyday automatically because that data from the website is updated daily.

For example:

Here I have 3 .csv files:

```
1.csv
2.csv
3.csv
```

and here I have 3 tables created on Kusto to store each csv data respectively:

```
Table_1
Table_2
Table_3
```

The question is: **Is it possible to automate and schedule the data push/load from local CSVs to Kusto?** The data push/load type is `Replace` for now but might need to be `Append` in the future.

I was recommended Flow (https://preview.flow.microsoft.com/en-us/) to check if any similar templates were set up already. However, I was not able to find any and am new to these tools so I need help from someone who knows about this. Thanks so much in advance. Please let me know if you need any further information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

if you want to control the schedule:

- you can use any of the ingestion client libraries to automate this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/api/
- or, if you prefer simply invoking a readymade utility, there are also [LightIngest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/tools/lightingest), and [Kusto Ingestion Tools (KIT)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-ingestion-tools/tree/master/kit)

an alternative approach would be:

1. have the CSV files you generate uploaded to cloud storage once they're created.
2. setup a data connection for the storage container they're uploaded to, so that any file that gets uploaded to it is automatically ingested into your cluster: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/ingest-data-event-grid

Comment: Thank you, Yoni! I used python with azure-kusto library to ingest data to kusto, which is part of your first suggestion. I've successfully pushed data into my test table. (Reference: https://github.com/Azure/azure-kusto-python/blob/master/azure-kusto-ingest/tests/sample.py) However, one drawback I found so far is that the data is always appended instead of being replaced. Plus, this python script cannot be fully automated because it will ask for an authentication code each time. So I will try to  test your other suggestions because I believe some of them would definitely be better.

Comment: 1) Kusto/ADX is an append only technology. if you want to replace data in the table, you'll need to first drop existing data, and then ingest new data (or vice versa); 2) a more sophisticated technique would be ingesting the new data to "temporary" table, then swap both tables using the `.rename tables` command (and then, dropping the no longer relevant table); 3) the python library supports AAD application authentication, which allows running in non-interactive / un-attended mode

Comment: I've added `.drop table ifexists` and `.create table` in my python code so right now data replacement is realized. Now I'm working on part (3). Thanks for your help!